Pxeboot - how to set network interface speed?
I can successfully do a PXE boot but the initial load of initrd and kernel is very slow because it drops back to 100Mbit instead of Gigabit. (This probably means it is actually causing all sorts of chaos with mismatched speed on the switch. It seems slower than I'd expect for even 100M)
Once the kernel/initrd are loaded and it boots them, back up to gigabit speed.
This is a boot config file I've used:
DEFAULT vesamenu.c32
PROMPT 0

# Option 1 - Local Boot 
LABEL bootlocal
    menu label ^Boot From Disk
    menu default
    LOCALBOOT -1

LABEL centos9
  menu label ^Network boot
  kernel images/centos9/vmlinuz
  append initrd=images/centos9/initrd.img ip=dhcp inst.ks=http://192.168.1.128/ks/client1.cfg

Any ideas on how to set the interface to full duplex in the PXE environment??
Maybe some Lua script to set it?

I don't think Linux / UNIX is involved here at all, assuming your PXE is supplied by your machine's firmware. The network card driver might simply not support Gigabit ethernet. Oh, and by the way, "Full Duplex" does not imply Gigabit ethernet.

This is likely a driver issue but it could be a hardware issue.  The driver could come from bios, uefi, or your boot loader itself.   There can't be a "speed mismatch" -- the host and switch must negotiate the same protocol or nothing will work at all.  If this was a hardware issue, maybe your cable is bad, but then gigabit wouldn't work later.  It could be tftp is slow, in which case switching to ipxe/http would help a lot.  Is the switch actually telling you this is 100M or does it just feel like that?
